# roles hierarchies and owd

Tags: configuration

I have 3 roles A,B,C in the same order,my requirement is to make C to create.read records,but A,B cant see records and also another 3 roles X,y,Z,z can read record and x y can not read.Finally C records cannot be visible to z.pls help,iam a fresher/.

Comment: I believe if you can document your question with more details and some realistic roles, it will help us to provide a solution. Just a pointer, you should create your roles based on how you want your data to be shared and keep in mind OWD while creating roles.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your OWD is to Private:

1. If A and B is boss of C then he will be able to see the record as per role hierarchies. You can restrict access from profile go to A AND B user profile remove the access to the particular object.
2. If your OWD is set to private then Z will not be able to see the record and to give access to x, y. You need to share the record with read only permission with C.

You can get more info [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14081/how-would-sharing-rule-work-in-the-below-scenario/14086#14086)

Comment: I NEED TO KNOW BASED ON ROLES..

Comment: Roles and OWD settings are related to some extent.

Comment: i got it by using sharing settings,like C role can be shared with B(read only), C role can be shared with C(read only), and also  Z role can be shared with Y(read only), Z role can be shared with Y(read only),

Comment: Glad to know :)

Comment: sir,suppose i have an candiate__ object,if i click save it has update replica object object of Candiate__c,i thought of writing a trigger.but am not getting any logic,,pls help

Comment: trigger updatingreplica on Candidate__c (After insert, After update) {
if(Trigger.isinsert){
list<Candidate_replica__c> ct=new list<Candidate_replica__c>();
for(Candidate__c acc: trigger.new){
system.debug('before creating'+ct);
Candidate_replica__c can=new Candidate_replica__c(Name=acc.Name,
                   
Age__c=acc.Age__c,category__c=acc.category__c,gender__c=acc.gender__c);
ct.add(can);
}
insert ct;
system.debug('after insert'+ct);
}
}i tried with this.replica object is created,if i edit and save,then it has to go to the actual object

Comment: HOW TO ACHIEVE THE ABOVE FUNCTIONALITY

Answer (score 0):

i got it by using sharing settings,like C role can be shared with B(read only), C role can be shared with C(read only), and also Z role can be shared with Y(read only), Z role can be shared with Y(read only),